# How to write \\ in awk as a string?

Tags: awk

file1

```
454.5  465.6532
```

I tried:

```
awk '{printf("%8.1f $ %11.4f\\\n", $1, $2)}' file1 > file2
```

but it gives just

```
   454.5 $    465.6532\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `\` needs to be escaped with a `\` - so to get `\\` use `\\\\`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '454.5  465.6532' | awk '{printf("%8.1f $ %11.4f\\\\\n", $1, $2)}'
   454.5 $    465.6532\\
```

Comment: Thank you very much